CodeForces Contest > 1761 \ Problem C (Set Construction) - How to solve this problem?
Guys I have been working on this problem since morning (4 hours ago) and still couldn't find a proper answer. How can I set the Subsets with these conditions? So for example an A Set is a subset of A2 but not subset of A3 and so on... How can I set the right algorithm? Can anyone help me?
problem link: https://codeforces.com/contest/1761/problem/C#

Problem Explanation:
The problem "Set Construction" from Codeforces requires constructing sets based on a given binary matrix, with certain rules for inclusion and comparison. Let's break it down:

Problem Explanation

Input:

You have a binary matrix b with dimensions n x n, where each element is either 0 or 1.


Output:

You need to construct n sets ( A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n ) consisting of distinct integers from 1 to ( n ).


Conditions:

Each set must be non-empty and distinct.
The matrix b indicates the subset relationship between these sets:

If b[i][j] = 1, then the set ( A_i ) must be a proper subset of ( A_j ).
If b[i][j] = 0, then the set ( A_i ) must not be a subset of ( A_j ).




Proper Subset:

A set ( A_i ) is a proper subset of ( A_j ) if all elements of ( A_i ) are in ( A_j ), and ( A_i ) is strictly smaller (i.e., ( A_i \neq A_j )).



Construction of Sets
To create the sets:

Start with each set containing its index: ( A_i = {i+1} ).
For each 1 in the matrix b[i][j], add the elements of ( A_i ) to ( A_j ).

Example
For instance, if the matrix b is:
0 1 0
0 0 1
0 0 0


It indicates ( A_1 ) should be a proper subset of ( A_2 ), and ( A_2 ) should be a proper subset of ( A_3 ). Thus, you might have:

( A_1 = {1} )
( A_2 = {1, 2} )
( A_3 = {1, 2, 3} )



This ensures the proper subset relationships as indicated by the matrix b.
Implementation Notes
The solution involves iterating over the matrix and ensuring that the sets are constructed according to the proper subset relationships. For each 1 in the matrix, the corresponding set relationships are established. If a zero is encountered, the corresponding sets must not have a subset relationship.
Example:
- Input
2
4
0001
1001
0001
0000
3
011
001

- Output
3 1 2 3
2 1 3
2 2 4
4 1 2 3 4
1 1
2 1 2
3 1 2 3


My C# code is here:

int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] b = new int[n, n]; // nxn size, 2d array def

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {     
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            b[j, k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //gets the matrix members
        }   
    }

    List<HashSet<int>> sets = new List<HashSet<int>>(); //a list for Sets

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(); // a new set for j. row
        set.Add(j++);

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            if(b[j,k] == 0) {
                set.Add(k++);

            } else if(b[j,k] == 1) {
                set.Add(k++);
                if(sets[k].Contains(k++))
                    set.Remove(k++);
            }
        }
            
        sets.Add(set);
    }
}

What should I do after that?
I have tried to solve the problem but I couldn't find a valid solution for the problem. I am expecting **help **for a *proper *and *valid *solution.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! First, please understand that SO is no coding service or tutoring site. You have to explain, how you want to solve the problem, at which point you got stuck und add debugging info for one specific issue. This said, you should start to properly parse your input. For example you could use Console.ReadKey().KeyChar to read single characters from Console. Or read a whole line and get the characters from the resulting string. After parsing the input make sure that it is correctly read by printing out b element by element. Then you can continue with the actual task.

Additionally, add some code to print out your result. If you still have issues, please edit your question and add your updated code that should comply the rules of a minimal reproducible example together with your current output.

@Markus I have edited and added my question clearly.

Have you at least read the contest materials/tutorial on the problem [https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/109256]? I can't see anything of the suggestions in your code.

Construct a graph over the n sets where there is a directed edge between set i and set j if b_{i, j} = 1. It is clear that each node in this graph is a proper subset of all nodes reachable from it.
To ensure each set is non-empty and distinct from all the others, we initialize each set with its index as the only element.
With the setup complete, perform a topological sort and merge the set of each element with its direct dependents.
for (int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); t-- > 0;) {
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var adj = new List<int>[n + 1];
    var sets = new HashSet<int>[n + 1];
    var ind = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sets[i] = new();
        adj[i] = new();
        sets[i].Add(i);
        var row = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            if (row[j - 1] == '1') {
                adj[i].Add(j);
                ++ind[j];
            }
    }
    Queue<int> q = new();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (ind[i] == 0) q.Enqueue(i);
    while (q.Any()) {
        int curr = q.Dequeue();
        foreach (int next in adj[curr]) {
            sets[next].UnionWith(sets[curr]);
            if (--ind[next] == 0) q.Enqueue(next);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        Console.Write(sets[i].Count);
        foreach (int el in sets[i]) Console.Write(" " + el);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

There is actually no need to explicitly construct a graph since the binary matrix b already gives us all the sets that are a superset of each set. We can simply iterate over the sets and add the index of each set to all sets that this set is a subset of.
for (int t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); t-- > 0;) {
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var sets = Enumerable.Range(0, n + 1).Select(_ => new HashSet<int>()).ToArray();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sets[i].Add(i);
        var row = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            if (row[j - 1] == '1') sets[j].Add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        Console.Write(sets[i].Count);
        foreach (int el in sets[i]) Console.Write(" " + el);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}


In hindsight, this is overkill since the problem states "if and only if".

thank you for your answer, but i don't know how to implement Graphs in code, so i didn't understand the answer at all.

@GameofHB-YT Explicitly constructing the graph wasn't actually necessary. I've added a shorter solution to my answer.

for your second solution, example 1::
Input:
2
4
0001
1001
0001
0000
Output:
2 1 2
1 2
1 3
4 1 2 3 4

@GameofHB-YT What's the issue? Note that there can be multiple valid outputs for the same input.
